# How to preserve empty lines when formatting .vue files in VScode?

Tags: vue.js, formatting, visual-studio-code

I am starting to hate .vue as a framework because all the VScode formatters I tried are deleting empty lines.

Everything is cool and fine with everything, except that empty lines are removed.

All my hard work of dividing code blocks with empty lines is just deleted every time I autoformat with Shift+Alt+F.

I have spend way too many days on this issue combining every time I come across it. But this time for .vue files I have no luck in finding a fix.

When I write:

```
    <div class="ui attached segment">





      <div class="ui grid">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="column eight wide computer sixteen wide tablet">

            <div>
              <div class="badge-wrapper">


                <discount-tag v-bind:item="item">
                </discount-tag>

                <div v-for="badge in item.badges" class="ui labels">

                  <a
                    class="ui label"
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: '#'+badge.color, color: '#fff'}"
                  >{{badge.label}}
                  </a>


                </div>
              </div>




            </div>

            <g-zoom :item="item"></g-zoom>

          </div>





          <div class="column eight wide computer sixteen wide tablet">

            <h1>{{ item.goods_name }}</h1>

            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
```

I expect the line-breaks and new-lines to be preserved, but instead it's mushed into this *machine code*:

```
    <div class="ui attached segment">
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column eight wide computer sixteen wide tablet">
            <div>
              <div class="badge-wrapper">
                <discount-tag v-bind:item="item"></discount-tag>
                <div v-for="badge in item.badges" class="ui labels">
                  <a
                    class="ui label"
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: '#'+badge.color, color: '#fff'}"
                  >{{badge.label}}</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <g-zoom :item="item"></g-zoom>
          </div>
          <div class="column eight wide computer sixteen wide tablet">
            <h1>{{ item.goods_name }}</h1>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
```

For .jsx, .js, .html, .php, .env, etc. files it's all good. Except for .vue

Basically what I'm looking is for this line of setting to work:
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "vscode.html-language-features"

in VScode user settings

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -3,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "vscode-typescript",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "vscode.html-language-features",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "aeschli.vscode-css-formatter"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
}
```

Vetur extensions is basically the things, which knows where html ends and js/css begins. And you can choose your formatter there. But you can't choose the VScodes built in formatter. It just ignores that setting.

Could somebody Please, please help in fixing or circumventing this issue, so that I would have autoformatting AND preserve empty newlines and linebreaks?

Comment: That spaghetti machine code horror looks quite idiomatic and nice IMO while the majority would think your excessive whitespace is the offender. I think you're rowing in the wrong direction, why not get comfortable with the code styles you'll likely see everywhere? This isn't a fault of Vue.

Comment: No no. It's not anybody's fault. It's done like that on purpose, I know. It just takes me exponentially more time to understand what am I looking at this way. I like to divide my code in neat code blocks by function. (webpack and babel are compiling it all in one line for production at the end anyway. It's just for the development part). Any help would be Very Very appreciated.

Comment: Try setting VS code's setting `formatOnSave` to false. It will tell you if the change is made by VS code or by vue-cli/eslint.

Comment: Formatting on save is disabled currently in VScode general settings and extension settings for "vue style beautify config". I format with Shift+Alt+F. 

After disabling all extensions, .vue formatting kicks in, when I install "Vetur", extension. 

I tried all formatters for Vue I found. Maybe I missed something. Maybe there is a setting on one of them to turn the feature off. Maybe formatters  clashed somehow. idk.

Comment: Have you tried using the default VS code formatter rather than an extension?  I had a similar issue and solved it by looking for "preserve white space" in the settings, and setting my default formatter to HTML language features.

Comment: I just realized the same thing.
Thank you!
I realized that what I'm looking for is for this to work:
"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "vscode.html-language-features"
But Vetur, just ignores this setting. Did you ever succeed in making it work?

Comment: Vetur is just basically the extension which knows where in a vue file html ends and js/css begins. And for each portion you can choose a formatter. But it doesn't allow to choose the default vs codes formatter. Is there maybe another html formatter, which works exactly like vs codes built in one and which you Can choose in those Vetur settings?

Answer (score 0):

I got formatting to work perfectly for the HTML, JS and CSS part just by simply telling VScode (in the bottom right corner), that a .vue file should be formatted as a HTML, but now I lost the Vue syntax highlighting.

No idea how to get that back.

That's a question of its own.
[How to tell VScode to format file-type A as file-type B, while preserving syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940400/how-to-tell-vscode-to-format-file-type-a-as-file-type-b-while-preserving-syntax)