# How to tell VScode to format file-type A as file-type B, while preserving syntax highlighting?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I had this problem:
[How to preserve empty lines when formatting .vue files in VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930318/how-to-preserve-empty-lines-when-formatting-vue-files-in-vscode/60939783#60939783)

I solved it by telling VScode (bottom right corner) that a .vue file should be formatted as a .html file.

That fixed the formatting issue, but I lost syntax highlighting for vue attributes in the html tags.

I need to get VScode to format file-type .vue as .html, while preserving syntax highlighting.

How can that be done?

Syntax highlighting for .vue comes from extensions.

I tried Vetur extension and vue-beautify extension. They highlighted the syntax but didn't format the .vue file correctly (for me at least)

In tried to add the following line in the VScode's global settings.json

```
{
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    }
}
```

But it didn't work for both of them.

Vetur just ignored the setting and formatted the .vue file following Prettier rules. (which you can't change in Vetur settings)

While with vue-beautify threw that there's no formatter installed for .vue files. Although I explicitly specified that I want to use the build in HTML formatter.

How can I force VScode to use the built in HTML formatter for .vue files, while still using all the rest of the features that "Vetur" or "vue-beautify" provide?

OR

How can I tell "Vetur" or "vue-beautify" extensions' "Prettier-html" module to preserve empty newlines?

UPDATE:
- tried "unibeautify".. but no support for "preserve-max-newlines" feature for vue
- and "beautify" - no support for vue at all.
- and "pretier" - no support for "preserve-max-newlines" for vue

Comment: Have you tried disabling the linter rule that removes the newlines?

Comment: That's the thing, that I don't know how to disable that. In this case Prettier's rule - which is what Vetur uses. And as far as I know, Vetur is the only VScode's help with vue files in particular, in things besides beautifying code.

Comment: How can I perhaps force Vetur to use the inbuilt HTML beautifier for the html part of the code? The inbuilt HTML parser which came with VScode is just what I'm searching for, but no way to connect it to Vetur (or some other Vue code helper for VScode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vetur currently doesn't support switching to the built-in HTML formatter, but you could request that as a new feature in [Vetur's issues](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues).

Since the root problem seems to be the collapsing of newlines, I propose different solutions that address only that problem:

- Switch Vetur's HTML formatter to `js-beautify-html`, and configure it to preserve newlines
- Surround the newlines with ignore-comments
- Disable Vetur's HTML formatting

### Option 1: Use `js-beautify-html`

In VS Code preferences, set Vetur's HTML formatter to [`js-beautify-html`](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/formatting.html#js-beautify-html):

[image: screenshot of <code>js-beautify-html</code>]

Then in [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) (*Choose `Preferences: Open settings (JSON)` from command palette*), add the JSON block shown below. The key is to set `max_preserve_newlines` to a high number that allows your desired number of newlines.

```js
"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "js-beautify-html": {
        "max_preserve_newlines": 10000, // Maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk (0 disables)
        "preserve_newlines": true // Whether existing line breaks before elements should be preserved
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Use ignore-comments

The advantages of ignore-comments:

- Disables formatter/linter while also documenting intentional whitespace, which is important for readers/maintainers
- Can be easily enabled/disabled per section of code

Vetur's default HTML formatter is `prettyhtml`, which internally uses `prettier`, so you could utilize Prettier's [ignore-comments](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html):

```html
<div>
<!-- prettier-ignore-start -->



<!-- prettier-ignore-end -->
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

If you switch the HTML formatter to `js-beautify-html`, use the corresponding [ignore-comments](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#ignore-directive):

```html
<div>
<!-- beautify ignore:start -->



<!-- beautify ignore:end -->
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

### Option 3: Disable Vetur's HTML formatting

Setting Vetur's HTML formatter to `none` in settings would disable the formatter for HTML sections in `*.vue` files. While this resolves the unwanted formatting of collapsing newlines, it has the obvious side effect of disabling *all* formatting in Vue templates, which might be acceptable for your usage.

Answer (score 3):

To tell VScode to format file-type A as file-type B

1. open your file in vscode
2. `Ctrl+Shift+P` (or View -> Command Palette from the menu)
3. and then type `Change Language Mode`
4. type the name of programming language (for exemple sql,C++ ...)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem with `*.html` files as `vue-html`, in my VueJS project, I use separate files for `html`, `ts` and `css` and I configure my Visual Studio Code to detect `*.html` files as `vue-html` 'language type' from Vetur :

```json
// VSCode user settings.json
"files.associations": {
  "*.html": "vue-html"
},
```

So same as you, format doesn't work if langage is vue-html or Vue so I have to change from vue-html
[image: file language vue-html]

to HTML langage to make format works but I loose the syntax highlighting.
[image]

To solve the problem here is my solution :

1. Install [Beautify extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) on VSCode
2. Add language type under the file type to match the same 'formatter style' :

```json
// VSCode user settings.json
"beautify.language": {
    "css": [
      "css",
      "scss" // Format scss laguage type as beautify do for css files
    ],
    "html": [
      "htm",
      "html",
      // this line below fix my issue
      "vue-html", // Format my .html files configured as vue-html files as beautify do for HTML language
      "vue" // Exemple to Format Vue langage as HTML files
    ]
  },
```

*Check Beautify docs for more infos about this params*

---

### **I think it's exactly what you mean by "How to tell VScode to format file-type A as file-type B, while preserving syntax highlighting?"**

**I keep syntax highlighting for Vue template because my file is still considered as vue-html and I get the format style as an HTML file.**